# looking for a way to re enable labels without specifying which ones vb.net

Tags: vb.net, properties, onclick, label

I am looking for a way, if its even possible, to re enable a label without actually needing to use its label name?

I have a game with labels I am using as click able boxes. The first box becomes disabled after the click event occurs, I want after the second box is clicked to re enable that first box.  Any Ideas? Here is the code for the first two box click events.

Edit: there will be 15 labels, 2 can be chosen at a time. The first will be disabled so that it can't be chosen a second time.

```
    Private Sub lblMemory1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblMemory1.Click

    Dim intClickBox As Integer = 1
    Dim intClickAnswer As Integer

    intClickAnswer = GuessClick(intClickBox)



    If blnActive = False Then
        blnActive = True
        whatClicked1 = intClickBox
        lblMemory1.BackColor = Color.Green
        lblMemory1.Text = intClickAnswer.ToString
        lblMemory1.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        lblMemory1.BackColor = Color.Cyan
        lblMemory1.Text = "X"
        lblMemory1.Enabled = False
    End If

    If blnActive = True Then
        whatClicked2 = intClickBox
        lblMemory1.BackColor = Color.Green
        lblMemory1.Text = intClickAnswer.ToString
        lblMemory1.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        lblMemory1.BackColor = Color.Cyan
        lblMemory1.Text = "X"
        blnActive = False
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub lblMemory2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblMemory2.Click

    Dim intClickBox As Integer = 2
    Dim intClickAnswer As Integer

    intClickAnswer = GuessClick(intClickBox)



    If blnActive = False Then
        blnActive = True
        whatClicked1 = intClickBox
        lblMemory2.BackColor = Color.Green
        lblMemory2.Text = intClickAnswer.ToString
        lblMemory2.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        lblMemory2.BackColor = Color.Cyan
        lblMemory2.Text = "X"
        lblMemory2.Enabled = False
    End If

    If blnActive = True Then
        whatClicked2 = intClickBox
        lblMemory2.BackColor = Color.Green
        lblMemory2.Text = intClickAnswer.ToString
        lblMemory2.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        lblMemory2.BackColor = Color.Cyan
        lblMemory2.Text = "X"
        blnActive = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This question is not clear. What is the rule, if one label clicked, which other label need to be re enabled? I guess there won't be simply two labels in your apps

Comment: There will be 15 labels to click, only 2 can be chosen, the first will be disabled so it can't be chosen a second time.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
    Public Sub game(sender As Object)
        Dim lbl As Label = sender
        If lbl.Enabled Then
            For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
                Dim lbl2 As Label = Me.Controls(i)
                If Not (lbl2.Enabled) Then
                    lbl2.Enabled = True
                    GoTo exitLoop
                End If
            Next
        End If
exitLoop:
        lbl.Enabled = False
    End Sub
```

then in each label just call the game sub and pass sender like so...

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    game(sender)
End Sub
```

this will allow only 1 label to be diabled at any give time...
you can also (within the loops) use lbl and lbl2 to set the properties for each label.
if you use a var to save the name of the first textbox you can also specifically re-enable only that box...
let me know if you want the code for that too.